# What should I do if I see same question?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

I have seen same question but on different stackExchange.

What should I do now to eliminate same/repeated question?

Comment: There are some relevant answers to a similar question at: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/235650

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I notice this, I leave a comment under each version: "cross-posted on [the other site], with a link to it". This at least tells those who are considering writing an answer that their work may be redundant.

I also suggest to the author that cross-posting is discouraged and they should ask on one site at a time.

These comments usually have enough effect: one of copies gets either closed, or deleted, or migrated.

Comment: Thank you @Sally :)

Comment: Caution should be exercised before closing, deleting or migrating duplicate questions while the Joomla Stack Exchange website is still in "BETA".

Comment: Thanks @NeilRobertson, I have seen few questions repeated in SO and JSE sites. I have just written the comment. should i raise delete/closed flag as well?

Comment: I'd exercise caution when deleting a post in favour of a post on JSE or migrating a question to JSE as until we are out of Beta, it's my understanding that all the answers could be lost.